# Does python always call __del__ synchronously?

Tags: python

The python documentation for [`__del__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) explains that an object's `__del__` method can be called when its reference count is reduced to zero.  Is it always called immediately (i.e. synchronously)? Or is it possible that the `__del__` method will be called "at some point in the future"?

Furthermore, does the answer to this question apply to Python in general?  Or is some latitude granted to the language implementation? (I use CPython.)

For this question, assume the following:

- The objects in question inherit from `object`.
- The objects in question have a custom `__del__` implementation.
- The objects' custom `__del__` implementation does NOT create new references to any objects.
- The objects in question are NOT part of a reference cycle.
- The interpreter is not in the process of shutting down.

From what I can tell, there seems to be a lot of confusion around this topic.  In an effort to side-step some unnecessary discussion, let me give some examples of unacceptable answers:

- "Don't use `__del__`!  It's confusing!"
- "Don't use `__del__`!  It's not 'pythonic'."
- "Don't use `__del__`, use a context manager instead."
- Any answer that makes an assertion about what is or isn't guaranteed without citing a credible source.  (Please feel free to cite other SO answers, but don't rely on them as your sole source.  "Credible" in this instance means something from the documentation, or a reputable person, or maybe even the CPython source itself.)

To rephrase this question with an example, consider this code:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __del__(self):
        print "C.__del__:", self.i

print "Creating list"
l = [C(0), C(1), C(2)]

print "Popping item 1"
l.pop(1)

print "Clearing list"
l = []

print "Exiting..."
```

which produces the following output:

```
$ python test_del.py
Creating list
Popping item 1
C.__del__: 1
Clearing list
C.__del__: 2
C.__del__: 0
Exiting...
```

Notice that in this example, `__del__` *was* called synchronously.  Is that behavior guaranteed by the language?  (Keep in mind the assumptions listed above.)

Comment: What is your use case where the answer matters?

Comment: If I can rely on this behavior, it allows for a cleaner API design.  Instead of forcing my library's users to remember to call some special "cleanUp()" function on the objects I've given them, I can just put the necessary clean-up code in __del__.  This is the essence of good RAII-based API design in C++, for example.

Comment: But how does knowing *when* __del__ is called change that? (The object will in any case be deleted *at some point*)

Comment: A fair question; thanks for raising it.  In my code as it stands now, I have an assertion that is catching "forgotten" clean-up of certain objects.  It isn't strictly necessary; it's just there to catch programmer errors ("did you forget something?").  If I *know* that the object should have been cleaned up by now, then it's a valid check.  But if the object could legitimately be on some "to-do" list somewhere, then I can't yell at the programmer (via an assert) for not cleaning it up yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From The Python Language Reference (Python 2.7.3 edition), [Chapter 3, Data model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> Objects are never explicitly destroyed; however, when they become unreachable they may be garbage-collected. An implementation is allowed to postpone garbage collection or omit it altogether — it is a matter of implementation quality how garbage collection is implemented, as long as no objects are collected that are still reachable.
>
> > **CPython implementation detail:** CPython currently uses a reference-counting scheme with (optional) delayed detection of cyclically linked garbage, which collects most objects as soon as they become unreachable, but is not guaranteed to collect garbage containing circular references. See the documentation of the `gc` module for information on controlling the collection of cyclic garbage. Other implementations act differently and CPython may change. Do not depend on immediate finalization of objects when they become unreachable (ex: always close files).

Comment: Sigh.  How did I miss that?  I spent my time reading the documentation on `__del__` itself, which doesn't make clear what is implementation defined.  It only says that `__del__` is called "called when x‘s reference count reaches zero".  But the paragraph you cited makes it clear as day.

Comment: Accepting this answer, but please also see @Andrew's answer (below) for a link that is very relevant to this discussion concerning PyPy.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is not guaranteed by the language.  For instance, see [PyPy's documentation on their garbage collection scheme](https://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#differences-related-to-garbage-collection-strategies) which explicitly states that the time at which `__del__` is called in PyPy is different from CPython.

If your object is not part of a reference cycle then I understand that this behavior is reliable in CPython, but I am not aware of any explicit guarantee.

Comment: Great link, thanks.  It gives me three impressions: (1) The language spec is vague, but it seems to imply that the delete-immediately behavior IS expected. (2) That was an arbitrary decision, probably influenced by the CPython implementation.  (3) It actually *doesn't matter* what the "official" answer is, because the authors of PyPy, Jython, and IronPython won't adopt CPython's reference-counting scheme.  This fact means that the `__del__` behavior is defacto "undefined" whether the standards-writers care or not.

Comment: I can't speak to whether the language spec is unclear on this point, but from a practical standpoint I agree that the behavior is undefined and should not be used except in cases where you really do want code to run exactly when the object is removed from memory (which seems like an unlikely use case).

Comment: Also, a note: Even if CPython is the only target, I do not feel one should write code that assumes an object is not a part of a reference cycle.  An object can become part of a reference cycle due to circumstances external to the object itself.